# Is this conclusion's grammar correct?

Tags: relative-pronouns, modifiers, logic

I have a reading passage, then a lecturer casts doubt on the reading using three main points. I want to write a summary of the reading and the lecture.  Now I want to ask you about this conclusion:

> The reading says .... . However, the lecturer mentions.... . the lecturer gives a compelling argument (or compelling arguments ?) to clarify his point view which demonstrate that the lecturer was correct (or true?)

I also want to ask about *which* in that sentence. Have I used it correctly?

If you know a better way to say that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Argument* may be either plural, if you are distinguishing several arguments, or singular, if you are speaking of a coherent presentation (which may include many subpoints) tending to a single main point.
2. Only propositions may be *true* or *false* in this sense. An argument is usually *valid* or *invalid*, and a position or viewpoint or the person holding it is *correct* or *incorrect*. (There are lots of other terms you could use here; you may look them up in a thesaurus and examine actual usage in a corpus such as Google Books or the BYU corpora.)
3. *Which* is OK, but your structure puts it in the wrong place; as the sentence stands you are saying that it is the *viewpoint* (or *point of view*, but not <sup>✲</sup>*point view*) which demonstrates ..., whereas what you mean is that the *argument* demonstrates ...
4. (Not something you asked) The NP *the lecturer* should not be repeated within the same sentence except for unusual emphasis. Replace it with the personal pronoun.

A couple of possibilities then:

> The lecturer clarifies his point of view with a compelling argument which demonstrates that he was correct.
>   The lecturer offers compelling arguments which demonstrate that his point of view is correct.

Or you could make it even shorter:

> His compelling arguments demonstrate that this point of view is correct.